# XSLT - Lookup value from other part of xml inside foreach

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root xmlns="http://1.local/1.xsd">
    <Definitions>
        <FileTypes>
            <FileType ID="1" Name="FileType1"/>
            <FileType ID="2" Name="FileType2"/>
            <!--... - lots of file types-->
        <FileTypes>
    </Definitions>
    <Files>
        <File Name="File1" FileTypeID="1" />
        <File Name="File2" FileTypeID="1" />
        <File Name="File3" FileTypeID="2" />
        <!--... - lots of files-->
    <Files>
</Root>
```

For each file, I need to get its Name attribute and for its FileTypeID lookup corresponding file type name

So example output would be:
File name: File1
File type: FileType1

File name: File2
File type: FileType1

File name: File3
File type: FileType2

This is XSLT I have so far but I'm not sure how to lookup name of file type.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:l="http://1.local/1.xsd"
  exclude-result-prefixes="l"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/plain" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="l:Root/l:Files" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l:Root/l:Files">
    Why
    <xsl:for-each select="l:File">
          File name: <xsl:value-of select="@Name">
          File type:
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `xsl:key` here to look up the FileTypes

```
<xsl:key name="FileTypes" match="l:FileType" use="@ID" />
```

Then, to get the relevant FileType name, you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('FileTypes', @FileTypeID)/@Name" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:l="http://1.local/1.xsd"
  exclude-result-prefixes="l"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/plain" />

  <xsl:key name="FileTypes" match="l:FileType" use="@ID" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="l:Root/l:Files" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l:Files">
    <xsl:for-each select="l:File">
          File name: <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
          File type: <xsl:value-of select="key('FileTypes', @FileTypeID)/@Name" />
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note your XML is not well-formed, as you do not have correct closing tags for `FileTypes` and `Files`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with XSLT you need to start with understanding its expression language XPath to navigate XML trees, you can select `//l:FileType[@ID = current()/@FileTypeID]/@Name`. Or in XSLT, as Tim has already posted, you can use a key to efficiently implement the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:l="http://1.local/1.xsd"
  exclude-result-prefixes="l"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/plain" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="l:Root/l:Files" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="l:Root/l:Files">

    Why
    <xsl:for-each select="l:File">
          File name: <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
          File type: <xsl:value-of select="//l:FileTypes/l:FileType[@ID=current()/@FileTypeID]/@Name"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, you need to make sure you put the correct namespace in your xsl transformation to actually match the values in you XML, and you were missing a few close tags in your XML.

For completeness I've included the fixed XML that I used for the solution

```
<Root xmlns="http://1.local/1.xsd">
    <Definitions>
        <FileTypes>
            <FileType ID="1" Name="FileType1"/>
            <FileType ID="2" Name="FileType2"/>
            <!--... - lots of file types-->
        </FileTypes>
    </Definitions>
    <Files>
        <File Name="File1" FileTypeID="1" />
        <File Name="File2" FileTypeID="1" />
        <File Name="File3" FileTypeID="2" />
        <!--... - lots of files-->
    </Files>
</Root>
```

Comment: Adjusted this to reflect Martin's anwser, since there is no need for the variable i used.